# Minimum script to extract the content from a page at another site in PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping

Very simple thing. I sometimes want to access urban dictionary but it is blocked where I am. 
Given a form like

```
<form method="get" action="<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<input type="text" name="what" value="" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

what do I need to add to have it return the content of the entry from urban dictionary for value entered? For example using CURL or getFile or something as simple as possible

Update:

This works!

```
<form method="get" action="">
<input type="text" name="what" value="" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?PHP
$what = isSet($_GET["what"])?htmlentities($_GET["what"]):"";
echo file_get_contents("http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=".urlencode($what));
?>
```

Comment: Off-topic: You should use `echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` to prevent script injection because PHP_SELF is partially user-supplied.

Comment: @Arch I suspected something like that. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: You could leave it empty as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very simple, very weird `file_get_contents($_POST['what']);`

Comment: Because you can enter `/path/to/something/that/user/shouldnt/see`

Comment: Ye, I think. But remember, your hosting can forbid it to work.

Comment: Only thing left is that what seems to be set regardless, so when I load the page I see the homepage of the site I want to search

Comment: `if (isSet($what))` is useless - you set it in line before :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some DOM parsing with PHP. You can use the native DOM parser in PHP5 (recommended, see here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-xmldomphp/), or a library like Simple HTML DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

You can then use your post data to choose the URL.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are looking for something like http://pici.picidae.net/ rather than programming something which will be blocked by your network anyway.

Comment: Nope. That site is blocked too. but my personal site is NOT blocked

Comment: @Emmerman - I do not even want to try to load that url :) I don't want to see the anti proxy page